# raspberry pi 3 (raspbian on sd card ) doesn't boot using linux mint laptop

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, raspberry-pi3, linux-mint, videodisplay

i tried both noobs and raspbian on sd card to try to boot the raspberry pi 3 but none of them seem to do the job (if the sd card is the problem ) 
when i power it up , there are 2 lights  , red and green
there is a sign that the keyboard and mouse are working , but still
NO DISPLAY on the laptop screen !!! 
p.S : i'm using an hdmi cable that used to be working with our tv .

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the install before attempting to boot? I did the same from my Linux Mint box and it did not format it properly the first time. You have to verify the install per the Raspberry OS install instructions before attempting to boot with it.

Once verified, make sure you insert the card while the power is disconnected from your Pi. Also make sure you have your HDMI, keyboard, and mouse plugged in BEFORE connecting the power the first time you boot. Also, if you plug the power in before the HDMI the Pi 3 will boot to a headless state, plugging in a monitor after this will not work. You will have to unplug the power and plug it back in with the HDMI left plugged in.